# visual studio 2010 search in specific files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was wondering is there a way in visual studio 2010 to search in specific set of files
for example search only in *.js or *.cs files?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you use the *Find in Files* command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), in the *Find Options* section, you can specify the type(s) of files to search in:

[image: Find in Files dialog]